# Dynamic assignment of user defined class in C++, all with the same public function

Tags: python, c++, dynamic, overloading

Firstly, I'm a physicist, so my coding experience and knowledge is limited so apologies if I'm not using the correct terminology or if an answer to this question already exists. I've been unable to find anything sufficiently similar that makes sense to me though.

Now, I'm performing Monte Carlo simulations of some quantum system and within this I need some specific polynomials. I have written classes for all such polynomials. They all take the same arguments when initialising (a string and an integer) and the only public method in all of them is similarly identical from an outward perspective (it takes in an array of complex doubles and outputs one complex double). The general picture is

```
class Polyi{
    public:
        Polyi(string type, int N){
            ::Set things up if needed::
        }

        complex<double> poly(complex<double> *z){
            ::Calculate the polynomial and return::
        }
}
```

Now, the polynomial I wish to use in a given simulation needs to be something I can input from the outside. I'm more used to Python so something like

```
if poly_type==i: polynomial = Polyi(type, N)
elif ...
```

is what I want to do. I'd then use `polynomial.poly(z)` in the subsequent code.

However, this is proving extremely difficult in C++ because I have to declare the type of class I'm using at assignment. I've tried a couple of things. I made a handler that contains all the individual polynomials. Didn't work. I also tried to make a base class to all of these including the `poly(z)` function and then overload it in each. I also fell short here. However, they probably didn't work because I'm an idiot, not because they're actually impossible to implement.

Therefore, how could I implement this kind of dynamic assignment, such that when I hit my actual calculation, I have a the desired polynomial, of whatever class, in the variable `polynomial` and I can just call `polynomial.poly(z)`? The most simple solution to this would be awesome if possible, because I'd like to be able to understand what the code is actually doing.

Thanks for any help you can offer me!

**EDIT:** Thankyou so much to everyone! There wasn't a single unhelpful comment/answer and a lot of great suggestions of things to look up. Thanks to everyone!!!

ps. To clarify, though it didn't seem to be a crucial point, the `type` variable defines a type of polynomial within a type of polynomial. So for example, for the Pn polynomials, Pn("1",N) = z1+z2+...+zN, Pn("2",N)=z1^2+z2^2+...zN^2 etc. On the more complicated side I have the Jack polynomials, which are indexed by a partition of integers (like 11122 or 223). I have no idea how to generate them so I download a file with them, hence why it's a string.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what does the string `type` relates to?

Comment: You can declare the object first, and then just assign to it (and have a proper [copy-assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator)).

Comment: It's a string of integers which defines the polynomial. The fact that it's a string is useful for some of the polynomials where I have text files defining all factors and powers involved. For the simplest example though, each integer in that string just defines the power of each `z` in a sum over all z's

Comment: Just confirming, you have a bunch of different types of polynomials (Polyi, Polib, Polyc) and want your switch statement to select which one to implement? Or you have one type of polinomial (Polyi) and are getting a no-default constructor error?

Comment: Joachin: That looks like it might work ... I'll have a closer look

Comment: IdeaHat: The former is correct. I have several polynomial types and I want to select which to implement

Comment: If you have several classes, you might want to read up on inheritance, virtual functions and polymorphism.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you mean by types is thing such as Chebychev polynomial, etc.. You might want to have a base polynomial class and multiple derived classes to implement the specific polynomial types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphism in C++ relies on pointers.

If you have a base class Poly and then child classes Polya, Polyb, Polyi.. etc.
you can have a `Poly*` actually pointing to a `Polya*`, however you cannot have a `Poly` containing a `Polya` because you will face type-slicing.

So you can have something like this :

```
class Poly_base
{
    public:
        Poly_base(string type, int N) {
            // Potentially do stuff that you do on ALL poly
        }

        virtual complex<double> poly(complex<double> *z) = 0;
}

class Polyi : public Poly_base
{
    public:
        Polyi(string type, int N):
            Poly_base(type, N)
        {
            // Stuff you would do only on Polyi.
        }

        virtual complex<double> poly(complex<double> *z)
        {
            // Your calculation for Polyi.
        }
}
```

NOTE the `virtual` keyword. This says : here is a method on my base class that can be reimplemented on child classes.
If you call poly on a `Poly_base*` pointer that is actually pointing to a `Polya` instance, then the reimplemented version will be called. (via the magic of vtables)

Then in main :

```
Poly *polynomial;
if (some_condition) {
    polynomial = new Polya(type, N);
} else if (some_other_condition) {
    polynomial = new Polyi(type, N);
}
polynomial->poly(z);
```

EDIT: You might want your type to be an enum instead of a string, so you can do a switch statement on it like so :

```
enum PolyType {
    polya = 0,
    polyb,
    polyi
}

Poly_base *polynomial;
switch (type) {
    case polya:
        polynomial = new Polya(type, N);
        break;
    case polyb:
        polynomial = new Polyb(type, N);
        break;
    case ....
}
```

EDIT2: you also probably don't need the type in your classe constructor.. The whole point of this architecture is that this information is contained in the instance you actually created. If you created a Polya, then it "knows" it is a Polya and not a Polyb.

Comment: This is definitely not meant as a crash course of polymorphism and inheritance in C++. read it up. Also Ideahat has a point : this screams factory. His implementation is cleaner. once you have mastered inheritance look this up too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is a perfect place for the factory design pattern.

```
class iPoly{
public:
    virtual ~iPoly(){}
    virtual complex<double> poly(complex<double> *z) = 0;
};

class Polyi : public iPoly {
public:
    Polyi(string type, int N);
    virtual ~Polyi(){}
    virtual complex<double> poly(complex<double> *z);
};

class Polyb : public iPoly {
public:
    Polyb(string type, int N);
    virtual ~Polyb(){}
    virtual complex<double> poly(complex<double> *z);
};


iPoly* make_poly(string type, int N) {
  if (type=="Polyi") {
     return new Polyi(type,N);
  } else if (type=="Polyb") {
     return new Polyb(type,N);
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to make `Polyi` and `Polyb` to inherit from `iPoly`?